# How to Mock Service Initialization Parameters in Service Fabric for Unit Testing similar to mocking the state using a mock class?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am writing Unit tests for a Service Fabric Reliable Service. 
My application is an OWIN hosted Stateless service,
I want to write Unit test for Communication listener, Which uses ***ServiceInitializationParameters*** class. I can't initialize a dummy object of this type since all the fields are read only and no public constructor is available. 
For State in service fabric, We can mock it by using a mock class which implements an interface for state.

Is there any similar way to mock the Service Initialization Parameters ?

Comment: You can initialize it using reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can't mock out ServiceInitializationParameters in the current release, but you will be able to in an upcoming release, so stay tuned for that.